# Similating a javascript click event on a specific page

Tags: javascript, dom, mouseevent

I know click simulation is a very very standard question but I cannot work out what is going wrong I am applying thefollowing scripts on a microsoft dom https://www.projectoxford.ai/demo/Emotion:

```
var l2 =  document.getElementsByClassName("imgUrl defaultvalue")[0];

l2.value = "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03442/DEBATE_FIRST_PIC_3442872k.jpg"

function simulate(element, eventName)
{
    var options = extend(defaultOptions, arguments[2] || {});
    var oEvent, eventType = null;

    for (var name in eventMatchers)
    {
        if (eventMatchers[name].test(eventName)) { eventType = name; break; }
    }

    if (!eventType)
        throw new SyntaxError('Only HTMLEvents and MouseEvents interfaces are supported');

    if (document.createEvent)
    {
        oEvent = document.createEvent(eventType);
        if (eventType == 'HTMLEvents')
        {
            oEvent.initEvent(eventName, options.bubbles, options.cancelable);
        }
        else
        {
            oEvent.initMouseEvent(eventName, options.bubbles, options.cancelable, document.defaultView,
            options.button, options.pointerX, options.pointerY, options.pointerX, options.pointerY,
            options.ctrlKey, options.altKey, options.shiftKey, options.metaKey, options.button, element);
        }
        element.dispatchEvent(oEvent);
    }
    else
    {
        options.clientX = options.pointerX;
        options.clientY = options.pointerY;
        var evt = document.createEventObject();
        oEvent = extend(evt, options);
        element.fireEvent('on' + eventName, oEvent);
    }
    return element;
}

function extend(destination, source) {
    for (var property in source)
      destination[property] = source[property];
    return destination;
}

var eventMatchers = {
    'HTMLEvents': /^(?:load|unload|abort|error|select|change|submit|reset|focus|blur|resize|scroll)$/,
    'MouseEvents': /^(?:click|dblclick|mouse(?:down|up|over|move|out))$/
}
var defaultOptions = {
    pointerX: 0,
    pointerY: 0,
    button: 0,
    ctrlKey: false,
    altKey: false,
    shiftKey: false,
    metaKey: false,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
}
var l =  document.getElementsByClassName("demo-bar-submit")[0];

simulate(l,"click");
```

Every command in the code above is done one at a time in the comand line of the website https://www.projectoxford.ai/demo/Emotion. Is this blocked somehow because nothing happens ? nonetheless when I click the button a change does indeed take place.

Comment: Did you mean JavaScript in your title? Because JavaScript is completely different from Java

Comment: It's not blocked you are just dispatching the event on the wrong element, the click event that triggers the functionality for that button is set on the `div.buttonMask` element not the `div.demo-bar-submit`

Comment: post the answer and I will make it the solution? (it worked)

Comment: Patrick Evans, how can you tell?